# Is there a way to reduce waiting time on compose network creation?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Is there a way to reduce the waiting time when creating macvlan networks in docker-compose.yaml?
please note that we are trying to create the networks via the compose yaml and not via the `docker network create` module.

We are using Ubuntu18.04 and Ubuntu20.04 with Docker Engine v19.03 & Compose v2.4.1.

```yaml
version: "2.4"
networks:
    test:
       name: test
       driver: macvlan
       driver_opts:
          parent: ens192
          macvlan_mode: bridge
       ipam:
          config:
             - subnet: 172.100.100.0/16
               ip_range: 172.100.100.0/16

    test1:
       name: test1
       driver: macvlan
       driver_opts:
          parent: ens224
          macvlan_mode: bridge
       ipam:
          config:
             - subnet: 172.200.100.0/16
               ip_range: 172.200.100.0/16

services:
    test-web:
        image: test:latest
        networks:
            test:
            test1:
        command: "/app/webapp"
```

When running the above code we are getting 15 seconds waiting **per network** until the application runs.